# Slack | Get message of pinned messages

Tags: slack

I'm looking for a way to get a daily message post with all the pinned messages as a thread. We use pinned threads to track issues and want to get a daily message of pinned items. Haven't found a way yet.

Thanks All!

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about creating a custom app to capture this data, 
'[pin_added](https://api.slack.com/events/pin_added)' event can help you to keep track of pinned messages in a channel.

For regular slack usage,

you can just view the pinned messages in a channel, it does not tell when the message was pinned.